# Show/hide div based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

So I found other answers online, but I'm curious to know why what I have isn't another valid solution. When I click a radio button no divs appear/disappear. I have display:none by default. (I also tried using CSS instead of JS and that also didn't work)

index.php file:

```
if(isset($_POST['pickupDelivery'])){
    if($_POST['pickupDelivery'] == "pickup"){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("pickupName").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("desiredPickup").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("deliveryAddress").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("desiredDelivery").style.display="none";
        </script>
        <style>
            #pickupName, #desiredPickup {
                display: block; 
            }
            #deliveryAddress, #desiredDelivery {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>    
        <?php
    } else if($_POST['pickupDelivery'] == "delivery") { 
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("pickupName").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("desiredPickup").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("deliveryAddress").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("desiredDelivery").style.display="block";
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you want the div's to be shown/hidden on page load itself?

Comment: you don't need both css and js, and it looks fine. can you explain what doesn't work?

Comment: By deault the four divs should be hidden. There are two radio buttons, if one is pressed than the first two divs should appear and if the other button is pressed than the last two should appear (and if they're toggled back and forth without a page refresh then the others should be hidden).                  @Shlomi I know I don't need both, but I tried both and neither worked. The divs don't show up when I select a radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should set everything as hidden.

```
<style>
     #pickupName, #desiredPickup, #deliveryAddress, #desiredDelivery {
       display: none; 
    }
</style>
```

and this should show and hide the fields according to the radio button

```
if(isset($_POST['pickupDelivery'])){
    if($_POST['pickupDelivery'] == "pickup"){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("pickupName").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("desiredPickup").style.display="block";
        </script>
        <?php
    } else if($_POST['pickupDelivery'] == "delivery") { 
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("deliveryAddress").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("desiredDelivery").style.display="block";
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the issue is in there. But I'll add it to my post.

Comment: @djd97 please make sure that the css is always in the header and only the script is changed according to the user selection.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. Now, I'm using a session to store the state of the radio buttons so if the page is refreshed before it's successfully submitted the button will keep it's state. How could I save the state of the div's so the correct divs remain displayed as well?

Comment: use the code in my answer and check against the state which divs to show.

Answer (score 0):

See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/Dhanck/8rjn9v68/1/

```
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      val = radios[i].value;
      document.getElementById("box1").style.display="none";
      document.getElementById("box2").style.display="block";
    }else{
     document.getElementById("box2").style.display="none";
      document.getElementById("box1").style.display="block";
    }
  }
```

Comment: I also need it to work without having to toggle between the two. What would I need to change for this to work: https://jsfiddle.net/8rjn9v68/2/

Answer (score 0):

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/5oszwuLn/1/)**

an example with JQ 
i don't know how your html looks so i made one myself

```
<div class="test">
    aaa
</div>
<div class="test">
    bbb
</div>
<div class="test">
    ccc
</div>
<div class="test">
    ddd
</div>
<div class="radios">
    <input type="radio" >
    <input type="radio" >

</div>
```

css :

```
div.test { display:none}
```

JQ :

```
var radio = $("input:radio")

$(radio).change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':first-child')) {
        $(".test:nth-child(1),.test:nth-child(2)").show()
        $(".test:nth-child(3),.test:nth-child(4)").hide()
    }else{
        $(".test:nth-child(3),.test:nth-child(4)").show()
        $(".test:nth-child(1),.test:nth-child(2)").hide()
    }
});
```

**or with just CSS**

see here  **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/5oszwuLn/2/)**

html :

```
<input type="radio" class="button1" >
<input type="radio" class="button2">
<div class="test1">
    aaa
</div>
<div class="test2">
    bbb
</div>
<div class="test3">
    ccc
</div>
<div class="test4">
    ddd
</div>
```

css :

```
div { display:none}
input.button1:checked ~ .test1,input.button1:checked ~ .test2 {display:block}
input.button1:checked ~ .test3,input.button1:checked ~ .test4 {display:none}
input.button2:checked ~ .test3,input.button2:checked ~ .test4 {display:block}
input.button2:checked ~ .test1,input.button2:checked ~ .test2 {display:none}
```

Comment: sorry. i don't know much javascript that's why i gave you a jquery solution.
all i can say is that these are the errors :Uncaught ReferenceError: delivery is not definedonclick.

i just hope the above answer with jquery or css will help you

Answer (score 0):

I think you could easily do that with jQuery

**jQuery**

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === 'pickup') {
    $("#pickupName").addClass("show");
    $("#desiredPickup").addClass("show");
    $("#deliveryAddress").removeClass("show");
    $("#desiredDelivery").removeClass("show");
  } else if ($(this).val() === 'delivery') {
    $("#deliveryAddress").addClass("show");
    $("#desiredDelivery").addClass("show");
    $("#pickupName").removeClass("show");
    $("#desiredPickup").removeClass("show");
  }
});
```

And simply add this to your CSS

**CSS**

```
.show{
  display: block !important;
}
```

But you are asking why your piece of code isn't working. Make sure that your script tags are before the body end or head end tag. Maybe then it works.